# Rust Ink - Execution finished with debug buffer: panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: CalleeTrapped'

Tags: ink, rust

I'm trying to make cross contracts calls on already deployed contract, I'm running the local subtrate node in debug mode, and I'm getting the following message when trying to preform cross contracts.

Here is the error:

```
ThreadId(34) runtime::contracts: Execution finished with debug buffer: panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: CalleeTrapped', erc20/lib.rs:102:14
```

Here is the `DeployedContract1` cross call function code:

```
        #[ink(message)]
        #[ink(selector = 40)]
        pub fn test(&self) -> u32 {
            self.platform_fee
        }
```

Here is the  `DeployedContract2 (erc20/lib.rs)` function source code:

```
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn test1(&self,token_contract: AccountId) -> u32 {
            
            let my_return_value: u32 =  ink_env::call::build_call::<<Self as ::ink_lang::reflect::ContractEnv>::Env>()
            .callee(token_contract) <--- ERROR points here
            .gas_limit(50000)
            .transferred_value(0)
            .exec_input(
                ink_env::call::ExecutionInput::new(ink_env::call::Selector::new([0, 0, 0, 40])),
                

            )
            .returns::<ink_env::call::utils::ReturnType<u32>>()
            .fire()
            .unwrap();
            my_return_value
            
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the gas limit?

Comment: @forgetso No sir, I'll do it and report back

Comment: @forgetso Didn't work sir, thank you anyways.

Comment: Are your contract constructors marked as [payable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70862535)?

Answer (score 4):

Your call to `fire()` returns a `CalleeTrapped` error which you subsequently turn into a panic by calling `unwrap`. This `unwrap` is where the panic should point to.

`CalleeTrapped` is a rather unspecific error and just means that the callee trapped (caused by a `panic` in Rust). The function you are calling is infallible if described correctly here. This only leaves some error in the selector.

I suspect that the selector you specified (`40`) encodes to `[40, 0, 0, 0]` because the `40` is interpreted as integer which is then SCALE encoded. SCALE uses little endian representation.